# mapping jms property to RabbitMQ

Tags: spring-integration

We use spring integration to communicate components using MQSeries and RabbitMQ.

With MQseries there are a lot of JMS properties that are used by customers.

We would like to add an intermediate function between the input and the output which makes a mapping of these properties (getting the jms_priority from mqseries and put in the output message the property "priority" for RabbitMQ).

Without the specific properties JMS it **works very well**.

Below the code we use:

```
<int:channel id="input" ></int:channel>
<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="jmsIn" connection-factory="connectionFactoryCaching"  channel="input" ...>

<int:service-activator id="sa1" input-channel="input" ref="serviceBean"  output-channel="output"/>
<bean id="serviceBean" class="com.poc.ServiceActivator"> </bean>

<int:channel id="output" ></int:channel>
<int-amqp:outbound-channel-adapter channel="output"  .../>

import org.springframework.amqp.core.MessageProperties;
```

The ServiceActivator code:

```
public class ServiceActivator {
    public org.springframework.amqp.core.Message convertMessageMQSeriesToRabbit (Message obj){

        MessageProperties messageProperties = new MessageProperties();
        try {
            messageProperties.setCorrelationId(obj.getJMSCorrelationID());
            System.out.println("getJMSReplyTo "+obj.getJMSReplyTo());
            System.out.println("getJMSPriority "+obj.getJMSPriority());
            messageProperties.setPriority(obj.getJMSPriority());
            System.out.println("getJMSType "+obj.getJMSType());
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Is this the right way to do it? In the convertMessageMQSeriesToRabbit method, what type of return object should be passed to the outbound? org.springframework.amqp.core.Message ?

In this method we want to fill all RabbitMQmessage properties (content_type, content_encoding, priority, correlation_id, reply_to, expiration, message_id, timestamp, type, user_id, app_id, cluster_id) with corresponding JMS value.

We also need to do it the other way (inboud rabbitMQ => outbound mqseries)

Answer (score 0):

No, Spring Integration uses its own abstraction `org.springframework.messaging.Message<?>`. You don't need to interact with it directly, simply use a header-enricher.

See `JmsHeaders` and `AmqpHeaders` for the constants.

```
<header-enricher id="headerEnricherWithShouldSkipNullsFalse" input-channel="fromJms" output-channel="toRabbit">
    <header name="amqp_correlationId" expression="headers.jms_correlationId"/>
    ...
</header-enricher>
```

For AMQP priority, the standard `IntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor.PRIORITY` value is used.

Also see the `DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper` and `DefaultJmsHeaderMapper` to see how the adapters map from `Message<?>` to/from RabbitMQ and JMS messageds.

Comment: Thanks for you code. It works fine when publishing a jms message i set the properties. But in some case the property is not set, so i have an error : `EL1008E: Property or field 'jms_replyTo' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.messaging.MessageHeaders' - maybe not public or not valid?`.  To prevent this error i added condition on expression (`expression="headers.jms_replyTo != null ? headers.jms_replyTo.XMSC_DESTINATION_NAME : '' ")` , but doesn't work. Do you have recommandations?